# How to replace $$ROOT for group in AWS DocumentDB - Feature not supported: $$ROOT

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I have a Node app interacting with a Mongo database. When running on the old setup or locally on MongoDB 4.4.0

When I deploy to AWS Document DB 3.6.0 and try to run a query with the below $group clause, I get an error that `Feature not supported: $$ROOT`

```
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$user_id",
      "total_paid_amount": {
        $sum: "$amount"
      },
      "data": {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
```

According to this doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/developerguide.pdf, $$ROOT is not supported in DocumentDB

How can I work around this issue, or perform the same query without pushing $$ROOT?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it's not clear why you need $$ROOT though

Answer (score 2):

Ended up just having to push the items I actually needed/wanted instead of all via `$$ROOT`

```
$push: {
  fieldOne: "$fieldOne",
  fieldTwo: "$fieldTwo"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion. You saved my day. I ended up doing something like this using Mongoose:

```
objects: {
 // $push: "$$ROOT"
 $push: (["_id", "__v", ...Object.keys(MongooseObject.schema.obj)].reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => ({
  ...accumulator,
  [currentValue] : `$${currentValue}`
 }), {}))
}
```

Comment: For people who have too much data to use `$push`, it's not integral to the answer; I added $$ROOT to a $group aggregation with `"$group": { ..."doc": { "$first": {   fieldOne: "$fieldOne", fieldTwo: "$fieldTwo"}}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Support for $$ROOT was added to Amazon DocumentDb in October 2021.